# Linux Kernel Config - Network / Firewall, make menuconfig

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, kernel

I have removed all the stuf from the Linux-Kernel i don´t need, now the Firewall is not working.
The firewall is starting but no rules inside and can not add rules.
What do i need to select/enable/module to get the firewall working?

This are my Linux-Kernel settings in **make menuconfig**:

```
  --- Networking support ---

  Networking options  --->
[ ]   Amateur Radio support  ----
< >   CAN bus subsystem support  ----
<*>   Bluetooth subsystem support  --->
< >   RxRPC session sockets
< >   KCM sockets
-*-   Wireless  --->
< >   WiMAX Wireless Broadband support  ----
<*>   RF switch subsystem support  --->
< >   Plan 9 Resource Sharing Support (9P2000)  ----
< >   CAIF support  ----
< >   Ceph core library
< >   NFC subsystem support  ----
< >   Packet-sampling netlink channel  ----
< >   Inter-FE based on IETF ForCES InterFE LFB  ----
[ ]   Network light weight tunnels
< >   Network physical/parent device Netlink interface
< >   Generic failover module



--- Networking options ---

<*> Packet socket
<M>   Packet: sockets monitoring interface
<*> Unix domain sockets
<M>   UNIX: socket monitoring interface
< > Transport Layer Security support
< > Transformation user configuration interface
< > PF_KEY sockets
[ ] XDP sockets
[*] TCP/IP networking
[ ]   IP: multicasting
[ ]   IP: advanced router
[ ]   IP: kernel level autoconfiguration
< >   IP: tunneling
< >   IP: GRE demultiplexer
[*]   IP: TCP syncookie support
< >   IP: Foo (IP protocols) over UDP
< >   IP: AH transformation
< >   IP: ESP transformation
< >   IP: IPComp transformation
< >   IP: IPsec transport mode
< >   IP: IPsec tunnel mode
< >   IP: IPsec BEET mode
< >   INET: socket monitoring interface
[ ]   TCP: advanced congestion control  ----
[ ]   TCP: MD5 Signature Option support (RFC2385)
< >   The IPv6 protocol  ----
[ ]   NetLabel subsystem support
-*- Security Marking
[ ] Timestamping in PHY devices
[*] Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter)  --->
[*] BPF based packet filtering framework (BPFILTER)  --->
< > The DCCP Protocol  ----
< > The SCTP Protocol  ----
< > The Reliable Datagram Sockets Protocol
< > The TIPC Protocol  ----
< > Asynchronous Transfer Mode (ATM)
< > Layer Two Tunneling Protocol (L2TP)  ----
< > 802.1d Ethernet Bridging
< > Distributed Switch Architecture
< > 802.1Q/802.1ad VLAN Support
< > DECnet Support
< > ANSI/IEEE 802.2 LLC type 2 Support
< > Appletalk protocol support
< > CCITT X.25 Packet Layer
< > LAPB Data Link Driver
< > Phonet protocols family
< > IEEE Std 802.15.4 Low-Rate Wireless Personal Area Networks support  ----
[ ] QoS and/or fair queueing  ----
[ ] Data Center Bridging support
< > DNS Resolver support
< > B.A.T.M.A.N. Advanced Meshing Protocol
< > Open vSwitch
< > Virtual Socket protocol
< > NETLINK: socket monitoring interface
[ ] MultiProtocol Label Switching  ----
< > Network Service Header (NSH) protocol  ----
< > High-availability Seamless Redundancy (HSR)
[ ] Switch (and switch-ish) device support
[ ] L3 Master device support
[ ] NCSI interface support
[ ] Network priority cgroup
[ ] Network classid cgroup
[ ] enable BPF Just In Time compiler
[ ] enable BPF STREAM_PARSER
Network testing  --->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of **netfilter** modules is so great I am only doing a partial list.

```
#
# Core Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_INGRESS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_FAMILY_BRIDGE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_FAMILY_ARP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_ACCT=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_OSF=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m
CONFIG_NF_LOG_COMMON=m
CONFIG_NF_LOG_NETDEV=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_CONNCOUNT=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_ZONES=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROCFS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMEOUT=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMESTAMP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_LABELS=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_GRE=m
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_AMANDA=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_H323=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IRC=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_BROADCAST=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_NETBIOS_NS=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SNMP=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SANE=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SIP=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SLP=m
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=m
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK_TIMEOUT=m
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK_HELPER=m
```

I don't know which firewall modules you are using but your are going to need some,most,all, or etc of the **NETFILTER** ones.

Here's what I would do.

Use the default config, and boot with that.

Make sure all your hardware and firewall is loaded correctly.

then

make localmodconfig

re compile the kernel.

done.

Comment: In my config are all Netfilters enabled as Module.

Comment: @Bandoler I added a suggestion.

Comment: I got the problem. I did make localmodconfig before i compiled the Kernel and make localmodconfig removed all the Netfilters.

Comment: boot a stock kernel. active firewall. lsmod and make sure all of those modules are enabled.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. it was my mistake. I accidentally removed all Netfilter by running make localmodconfig whit a disabled firewall.

Comment: Your welcome.  Yes, a disabled firewall would be a problem.  Glad you got it fixed.